# HTML form default action is running if jqueryui dialog div content change to original content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i am displaying html form inside jqueryui dialog and i am using jquery validation plugin to validate it.

Problem - when i submit form by changing content to original, default form action is running.

It is only happening if i change html content to original content before form closing.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var getOldForm = $("#send-pm-win").html();

  $("#pmLink").click(function() {

    $("#send-pm-win").dialog({

      modal: true,

      draggable: false,

      resizable: false,

      autoOpen: true,

      buttons: [{

        text: "Cancel",

        click: function() {

          $(this).dialog("close");

        },

        style: "outline: none;"

      }],

      close: function(event, ui) {

        $("#send-pm-win").html(getOldForm);

        $(this).dialog("destroy");

      }

    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your example does not clarify the issue. What is not working? What errors do you see in console if any?

Comment: @Twisty, On link click a html form should show in a dialog. when i click submit button, a loading gif image should show (instead of form) and on successful form submit, dialog content should be change to success message and finally after 5 seconds dialog should be close itself. Now i have done above thing and its working fine but the problem is when i reopen the form in dialog (after submit), jquery validation is not working instead its working in browser (default form action). Please note that i am reopening the form by using jquery html() method. help please

Comment: anybody please tell me solution

Comment: i am currently using javascript reload() method to reload the page after form submit unless i get the solution here.